# how to suppress to output of ::system("del *.log") from appearing in console

Tags: c++, c

I am executing `::system("del *.log")` in a win32 exe
The above code prints the output to exe console.
How can i suppress the output being printed to console?

Comment: A more straightforward approach would be searching for files yourself ([`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and removing them yourself too ([`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). And that approach wouldn't give you the problem you're facing now.

Comment: Or use `SHFileOperation()`.

Comment: Sure, that's even easier :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use redirection and redirect stdout to the nul file:

```
::system("del *.log > nul")
```

"nul" is a hidden file present in all directories, and all it does is discard everything written to it.

This will still show errors (if there are any). If you also want to suppress stderr, then:

```
::system("del *.log > nul 2>&1")
```

More info: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, you should use [`SHFileOperation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) instead.  There are variable flags available, such as `FOF_NO_UI`, for suppressing visual output to the user.  For example:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT FileOp = {0};
FileOp.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
FileOp.pFrom = "*.log\0";
FileOp.fFlags = FOF_FILESONLY | FOF_NO_UI;
SHFileOperation(&FileOp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
::system("del *.log > nul")
```